# Library/API for tor .onion web calls

Tags: c#, tor

Is there any `library` for making web requests to .onion websites? Without using Tor "`Firefox`" as for my needs I cant use tor browser.

I did some googling and did not found any solution regarding making simple web request to .onion without using tor browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a library per se, but the way to do this is to start tor and use it as a proxy for your application.  On Linux starting TOR without the browser is relativly straightforward.
edit:

looks like `tor.exe --defaults-torrc [path to torrc]` is the way to start it on windows.